# Optaplanner limit valueRangeProvider based on another entity

Tags: optaplanner

My planning problem is similar to employee rostering.

My planning entity looks like this

```
public class Menu {
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "productRange")
    private String productId = null;
    private String packId;
    private String date;
}
```

Now, I have a condition that if two packIds are "similar" then the productId for those on the same data must also be "similar" where being similar is defined by some business logic.

I added a hard constraint for this but number of products are ~3000 and it takes forever to run through all combinations. Is there a way to restrict the value range provider to achieve this (so that it only iterates over the similar products)?

Answer (score 0):

As per OptaPlanner manual: the value range of an entity must be independent of the planning variable's state. Any such dependence must be handle through (hard) constraints.

That being said, there are often more efficient models to deal with complexity you're describing. I've never seen anything below 10k instances that doesn't have an efficient way to solve them in 5 minutes or so. Typical scaling tricks include precalculation (valid combo's, hashing, ...), rule/scoring efficiency, nearby selection, ... and mulithreaded solving to top it off. It depends on the case and requires an in depth review.